# a problem with the updata function in the development of unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We encountered a problem with the updata function in the development of unity:

1. First, make a real-time judgment and record the acquired data in an array of the current script (for example, take the advancing person as the center, find a surrounding animal, and record it)
   (We are not sure how many times this judgment will be executed, because only one animal can be found at a time, so we use updata to do a continuous search to quickly find all the surrounding animals in this way)
2. After that, a judgment of traversing the array will be made, and the results will be displayed according to the contents of the array (continuing the previous example, suppose we want to display the "number of dogs" and "number of cats" in all the surrounding animals)
3. The problem we are encountering now: every time updata is executed, the array content will be reset, causing the data obtained before to disappear. We want to do: to a certain extent retain the information obtained during the last updata (because it only contains One animal, and we need to record more than one), and can update the "number of animals around the person" in real time as people move (when people are far away from animals, it is no longer recorded, and when a new animal approaches It is added to the array)
4. I am new to Unity, I hope I can get your help, thank you very much!

Comment: You may find Lists more useful for this purpose than built-in arrays as you can easily add and remove elements from them without needing to redeclare the array size. Any array (or list, or whatever variable you are using) declared at the class level should not be reset after Update(). If you share your code you may get a more specific answer.

Comment: So what is the issue? I don't think it is related to the `Update` method itself but rather your data structure design ...

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned objects being near a player, instead of using `Update`, I would look into [`OnEnterTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) or [`OnEnterTrigger2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) if your game is in 2D. I am not sure as to how you differentiate between various animals whether it be by tag, by derived class from a base class, by name, etc. but using `linq` on a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) should make it rather easy to find specific entries in a container. If you add more information to your question, I can narrow down how to help. I have assumed you have a base class called `Animal` and derive each animal to its own class, i.e. `Animal->Dog` or `Animal->Cat`. Here is a rather generic solution, let me know if you have questions.

With the snippet, I would assume this script would be on a sphere or circle that acts as a detection radius. All objects that are `Animal` would be [`tagged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) as `Animal` to make it easier to detect when specifically an animal enters the player's radius.

`Nearby.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HashSet<Animal> nearbyAnimals = new HashSet<Animal>();

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Animal")
        {
            nearbyAnimals.Add(other.GetComponent<Animal>());
            Debug.Log("Adding Animal!");
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Animal")
        {
            nearbyAnimals.Remove(other.GetComponent<Animal>());
            Debug.Log("Removing Animal!");
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // test - can be removed
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            FindNumberOfCatsNearby();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            FindNumberOfDogsNearby();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the number of cats near the player
    /// </summary>
    private void FindNumberOfCatsNearby()
    {
        // simplified thanks for derHugo's comment
        Debug.Log($"There are {nearbyAnimals.Count(animal => animal is Cat)} cats nearby", this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the number of dogs near the player
    /// </summary>
    private void FindNumberOfDogsNearby()
    {
        Debug.Log($"There are {nearbyAnimals.Count(animal => animal is Dog)} dogs nearby", this);
    }
}
```

`Animal.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Base class of all Animals
/// </summary>
public abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected abstract void AnimalMovement();
    protected virtual void MakeAnimalSound() { }
}
```

You can ignore the various functions I added to the class. They are only there to show what *could* be there to differentiate between each animal typing.

`Cat.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cat : Animal
{
    protected override void AnimalMovement()
    {
        // do unique cat movement
    }

    protected override void MakeAnimalSound()
    {
        Debug.Log("Meow");
    }
}
```

`Dog.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override void AnimalMovement()
    {
        // do unique dog movement
    }

    protected override void MakeAnimalSound()
    {
        Debug.Log("Bark");
    }
}
```

Once one enters, it is added to the `HashSet` and once it leaves, it is removed. To find specific entries of a type of `Animal`, traverse it using one of the functions I have as examples using `linq`. You can also iteratively loop over the `HashSet` using a `foreach` loop.

Here is a gif of the script working. In this example, dogs are cubes and cats are spheres.

[image: Example scripts]

Here are the components I am using to detect when the player enters the radius of an animal.

[image: Example]

Here are the components on one of the Animals. Both of them are the same except for which derived class is on them.

[image: Dog Example]

Comment: Instead of using `Where` you can directly do `Debug.Log($"There are {nearbyAnimals.Count(animal => animal is Dog)} nearby", this);`

Comment: And there might be cases where colliders is not what you want to use but rather simply define a nearby threshold/radius and go through a `static HashSet` of **all** existing animals ;)

Comment: @derHugo I'll update the snippet directly using `Count` seems a bit clearer. And that's true. If OP adds more detail to their question, can definitely change the implementation to a threshold based on existing animals. Thanks for the notes!